# MATLAB syntax highlighting in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ to edit MATLAB .m files. It works well in most respects, except that it seems that the lexer hasn't been updated to be compatible with recent version of MATLAB.

In particular, it doesn't highlight the 'classdef', 'methods' and 'properties' keywords when using MATLAB's object-oriented features. Is there a way to update the lexer, or a way to edit it myself so that it correctly highlights these keywords?

The highlighting on the keywords 'classdef' and 'properties' should be the same as the highlighting on the keyword 'end':

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find your Notepad++ install directory (c:\Program Files or c:\Program Files (x86), typically). You need to edit the language definition file. There's two of them: an ansi file called `lang.model.xml`, and a unicode file called `langs.xml`. Most likely you are using the ansi file if you are based in US/Canada.

Open the file in Notepad++, it's a generic XML file and can use the XML syntax highlighting. Search the file for "matlab". This should take you to a block of similar to this:

```
<Language name="matlab" ext="m" commentLine="%" commentStart="" commentEnd="">
    <Keywords name="instre1">break case catch continue else elseif end for function global if otherwise persistent properties return switch try while</Keywords>
</Language>
```

Edit the `<keywords>` section to include the words you want higlhlighted (Classdef, properties, etc.).

Then save the file and restart Notepad++. The new syntax settings should take effect.

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually found an alternate solution by searching on Google for "Notepad++ langs.model.xml" -- in the Style Configurator, if you select 'Matlab' in the left column and 'Instruction words' in the right column, then a keyword box appears that allows you to enter user-defined keywords. Entering 'classdef', 'properties' etc in there did the trick.

Comment: That's definitely the easier way. I missed that when I was poking around in the Settings and thought it was only for syntax coloring.

Comment: I tried editing `lang.model.xml` and restarting Notepad++, and the changes did not have any effect. Using the Style Configurator above did work.